# SOLR DIH throwing error "unsupported type : class java.lang.String"

Tags: solr

I'm trying to import a MS SQL field containing a PDF BLOB into SOLR and getting the following error:

> Exception while processing: attachment document :
>   SolrInputDocument(fields:
>   []):org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported type : class java.lang.String
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:246)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:476)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:416)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:480)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:461)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported type : class
>   java.lang.String

Here is the relevant part of my dataimport file:

```
<entity 
 name="attachment" 
 dataSource="dastream"
 processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
 dataField="items.CONTENTDATAFILE"
 format="text"
 <field column="content" name="body" />
 </entity>
```

Anyone have any idea whats wrong?
SOLR version is 4.10.3

Answer (score 2):

The field, *CONTENTDATAFILE*, is probably null for the entity in question...